# kafka FileNotFoundException with kafka-log-retention task

Tags: apache-kafka

After 23 days of running, I'm seeing this every five minutes:

```
ERROR Uncaught exception in scheduled task 'kafka-log-retention' (kafka.utils.KafkaScheduler) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/kafka-logs/events-7/00000000000000000000.index (No such file or directory)
```

My settings are:

```
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
log.cleaner.enable=false
```

Seems like a pretty simple setup. Right now, the system is not seeing a lot of volume either.

Any idea why I'm seeing this error?

Comment: Have you changed anything lately? What is the number of partitions of the topic `events`, is it 8 or more? Because it tells that it cannot open file for the partition number 7 and you have set `num.partitions=1` which is weird.  Did you delete any log files or the topic itself?

Comment: Nothing has changed. This seems to happen every 20 days or so.  Events topic has 500 partitions. Right now we're using 9 of those partitions.  No logs were deleted for the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Check the contents of `/etc/cron.daily/tmpwatch`. On my machine, it indicated that files in `/tmp` older than 10 days will get deleted. The solution would be to choose another directory for Kafka log.dirs config property. Not sure how you'd recover from the data loss, since the files were actually deleted. Luckily my cluster was not for production.

Comment: That doesn't exist in CentOS.  The only thing we have is /etc/cron.daily/lograte. It execute /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf  and the only folders in that conf file are /var/log/wtmp and /var/log/btmp